# Regarding semaphore up() and mutex_unlock() in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, mutex, semaphore

I want to know why we can use the semaphore up() in interrupt context while the same variant of mutex i.e mutex_unlock() cannot be used in interrupt context.
Below is snippet from kernel

```
/**
* mutex_unlock - release the mutex
* @lock: the mutex to be released
*
* Unlock a mutex that has been locked by this task previously.
*
* This function must not be used in interrupt context. Unlocking
* of a not locked mutex is not allowed.
*
* This function is similar to (but not equivalent to) up().
*/
void __sched mutex_unlock(struct mutex *lock)
{
  #ifndef CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCK_ALLOC
  if (__mutex_unlock_fast(lock))
    return;
#endif
__mutex_unlock_slowpath(lock, _RET_IP_);
}EXPORT_SYMBOL(mutex_unlock);


 /**
 * up - release the semaphore
* @sem: the semaphore to release
*
* Release the semaphore.  Unlike mutexes, up() may be called from any
* context and even by tasks which have never called down().
*/
void up(struct semaphore *sem)
{
  unsigned long flags;

  raw_spin_lock_irqsave(&sem->lock, flags);
  if (likely(list_empty(&sem->wait_list)))
    sem->count++;
  else
     __up(sem);
  raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore(&sem->lock, flags);
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(up);
```

Answer (score 3):

`mutex_unlock` takes a [mutex-internal spinlock in a non-irq-safe
fashion](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.15.2/source/kernel/locking/mutex.c#L1051) - e.g. `raw_spin_lock` may sleep if `CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT` is set - so if the timing is right, your `mutex_unlock` in IRQ context will deadlock.

Comment: `raw_spin_lock may sleep if CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT is set` - If I correctly remember, a function `spin_lock` simply doesn't disable interrupts and it is prohibited to call it from IRQ (because of a deadlock, you are right). Configuration `CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT` is unrelated here.

Comment: `mutex_unlock` is generally not irq-safe. I merely mentioned an example.